# start database reindexing via API

Tags: solr, indexing, azure-devops

I use an Azure DevOps pipeline to refresh test environment databases (master, web, core) with production data.

I want to make the re-indexing of the databases part of the  Pipeline, is there a way to start the reindexing of a database via an API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create your own API to do this, then call the sitecore API from within.

Something like this should work:

**Controller**

```
namespace YourNameSpace.Controllers
{
    public class YourController : SitecoreController
    {
        public ActionResult TriggerIndexRebuild(string indexName, string token)
        {
            bool success=false;

            // code to confirm token against config
            
            try
            {
                IndexCustodian.FullRebuild(ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName), true);
                IndexCustodian.RebuildAll();
                success=true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // log the exception
            }

            return Json(success, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

**Class to register route**

```
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class RegisterCustomRoute
    {
        public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            Register();
        }

        public static void Register()
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("SearchReport", "api/sitecore/triggerindexrebuild/{indexName}/{token}", new { controller = "Your", action = "TriggerIndexRebuild" });
        }

    }
}
```

**Config to register route**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor
          type="YourNameSpace.RegisterCustomRoute,YourNameSpace"
          patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']"
         />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Once setup, you should then just be able to call:

```
https://your-sitecore-instance/api/sitecore/triggerindexrebuild/sitecore-web-index/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
```

Sitecore Reference here:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/platform-administration-and-architecture/rebuild-search-indexes.html